# JsonSchema if enum property is one of several enum values, make X required, else for all other values make Y required

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I currently have a JsonSchema which has an enum field with 12 values, and lets say two other regular string fields in the same object, fields X and Y. If the value for the enum field is 1 of 3 out of the 12 enum values allowed, then I want to make X required, else if it's any of the other 9 enum values, then Y is required.

For example:

```
    {
       "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
          "efield": {
             "type": "string",
             "enum": ["n1", "n2", "...", "n12"]
          },
          "x": {
             "type": "string"
          },
          "y": {
             "type": "string"
          }
       },
       "if": {
          "properties": { "efield": { "in": ["n1", "n2", "n3"] } }
       },
       "then": {
          "required": ["x"]
       },
       "else": {
          "required": ["y"]
       }
    }
```

This is what it would look like idealy, though I know that the "in" keyword doesn't exist, closest I can figure at the moment is just using "allOf" and listing out 12 if statements for each enum value and which field is required based on each value, which feels kind of over the top / inelegant.

I also looked at "oneOf" and having two sub-schemas, one where 'efield' had the first 3 enums and x was required, and the other where efield had the other 9 enums and y required, but validation would complain about the enums, e.g. if I tried using an enum value from the second schema of 9 enums, it would complain that the value isn't in the first schema with the 3 values...

Are there any keywords that I'm missing, or any elegant ways of performing this use case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `enum` instead of your `in` keyword and it should be totally fine:

[image]

Comment: Hm, it works if I use one of the enums specified in the if statement, e.g. using "n1" without property 'x' will cause a validation error around the missing required property. But if I try using one of the other enums e.g. "n12", I get another validation error suggesting that "n12" is not a supported value, and that the only supported values are those provided in the if statement, e.g. "n1", "n2" and "n3"

Comment: Where do you get this error? This sounds to me that the validator in question is not working as it should be.

Comment: So I'm testing via Postman, the error appears to be getting thrown by the networknt.schema validator, then is being returned in the API response... There's not really anything that should be affecting the outcome between where the API is receiving the JSON and validating it

Comment: A good double-check is also available at (and it also does not throw any error in this case): https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/YAQKhvMl

Comment: Doubled confirmed https://jsonschema.dev/s/H29xN

Comment: Ok so at least I know then that this solution works and answers the outstanding question, and that there is another issue elsewhere, so I'll mark this one as answered, thanks!